# In Search Results order/sort by ordered quantity

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalogsearch, sorting

Please help me I want to see the products in Search Results order by ordered quantity means which products are more sold those products shows at first Thanks in

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.13.1.0...i am using enterprise edition

Comment: Actually i added custom code in Layer.php in
public function prepareProductCollection($collection) 
added these few lines $collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        'sales_flat_order_item AS order_item',
        'e.entity_id = order_item.product_id',
        'SUM(order_item.qty_ordered) AS ordered_qty')
    ->group('e.entity_id')
    ->order('qty_ordered DESC');
now i got the products list ordere by ordered quantity but here have 2 problems 1 is pagination and result count shows as 1 every result..


Please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving your issue is; by adding additional sort option like Relevance/Position sort option. In order for you to add a **"ordered quantity"** option you need to do the following:

- **First** copy `Config.php` from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php` and replace this function `getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()` with the following code:

---

```
public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
{
    $options = array(
        'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
        'ordered_qty'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Ordered Qty'),
    );
    foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
        /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract */
        $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
    }

    return $options;
}
```

---

- **Second** copy `Toolbar.php` from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` and replace this function `setCollection()` with the following code:

---

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        if($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'ordered_qty') {
            $this->getCollection()->getSelect()
                 ->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_item AS so', 'e.entity_id = so.product_id', 'SUM(so.qty_ordered) AS ordered_qty')
                 ->group('e.entity_id')->order('ordered_qty ' . $this->getCurrentDirection());
        } else {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

---

- **Third** to set **"Ordered Qty"** sort option as default for Search Result and Advance Search Result add/edit `local.xml` under your active theme folder `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml` and add the following:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>desc</param></action>
            <action method="setSortBy"><param>ordered_qty</param></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>desc</param></action>
            <action method="setSortBy"><param>ordered_qty</param></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>
</layout>
```

---

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply...
i don't want to show..orders list at front end ..in my app that front option is not there....
I want to enable that order in search result page, got that page path i.e app/code/core/Mage/catalogsearch/model/Layer.php


Pls help me.....

Comment: @latha with my solution, hiding ordered qty option from frontend is considered an option for you?

Comment: ok...thanq..
but what i done Layer.php is it not correct...

Comment: thanq...so much....
It's very nice... you save my time...
Thanq very much...
I done with only second step...it's working...nice answer..it's save my time...

Comment: @latha glad it worked for you :D ... feel free to market it as correct answer if you will

Comment: Can i ask another question?

Comment: @latha of course you can, but if its not related to this question try to submit new question post, I will try to answer it.

Comment: I was posted another question on duplicate products..

If you have any idea please help me

Comment: you can see that question in this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/how-to-duplicate-products-in-list

Comment: Hi...Aboodred.... 
I have to change the sort order in products listing page...   i.e featured products need to shows at first with order by to date means which products are going to end offer those feature products need to top in feature products block..non featured products are shows at below of featured products this block also sorted by quantity instock..Please help me...

Comment: I've done this exact thing but the query hangs. Not sure what's going on, any ideas?